# Isomorphism of direct products

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-isomorphism, direct-product

If $G, A, B$ are groups, it is not true in general that $G\times A\cong G\times B \implies A\cong B$. For instance, $G=\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}\times\cdots, A=\mathbb{Z}, B=\{1\}$.

What happens when $G,A,B$ are restricted to be **finite**? Are there finite groups $G,A,B$ such that $G\times A\cong G\times B$, but $A\not\cong B$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $G$ satisfies ACC and DCC (ascending and descending chain conditions) on normal subgroups, which applies when $G$ is finite, then $A \cong B$.

Thais follows from the [Krull-Schmidt Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Krull%E2%80%93Schmidt_theorem), which is moderately difficult to prove.